# TCP/IP и C#. Как получить список всех доступных удаленных конечных точек определенной подсети?

Tags: c#, сокет, tcp-ip

Подключение осуществляется с помощью сокетов.

**Задача** предельно проста. Есть приложение-клиент, которое должно взаимодействовать с приложением-сервером на другом компьютере. Для создания соединения необходимо знать удаленную точку `IPEndPoint`(ip-адрес и номер порта). Но не хотелось бы просить клиента вводить ip-адрес и номер порта в явном виде. Было бы идеально, если бы клиенту выводился на экран список доступных точек, к которым он может (или не может) подключиться.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли возможность программным способом определить все доступные удаленные точки конкретной подсети? Или все-таки клиенту самому придется вводить корректные значения ip-адреса и номера порта?

Comment: Скорее всего вам придется указать клиенту хотя бы одну конечную точку. Это будет либо конечная точка сервера, либо конечная точка сервиса, который знает конечную точку сервера.

Comment: клиент может послать широковещательный UDP пакет, который получат все узлы в сети. Все сервера, которые будут ожидать таких пакетов на указанном заранее порту могут сообщить в ответ свои ip:порт для tcp подключения

Comment: @Mike то есть клиенту надо будет знать хотя бы порт, верно?

Comment: Да, надо знать UDP порт. он не обязан совпадать с TCP портом. Все подобные протоколы имеют предопределенный порт, описанный в стандартах и зашитый им в исходники. Это точно так же, как принято к вебу обращаться по 80 порту, и по 443 в случае https

Comment: @Mike ага, понял. Спасибо

Comment: @Mike интересное решение. Пожалуй, так и поступлю, спасибо.